# Which is the behavior of @DirtiesContext when used together with KafkaEmbedded in unit tests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am developing some tests of an application that uses Kafka-streams that also uses Spring Boot 1.5, which imports version 1.2 of `spring-kafka`. In details, I am using `KafkaEmbedded` to avoid using a real running instance of Kafka.

In many examples on the net, I found that the configuration of such kind of tests uses the annotation `@DirtiesContext`, like in the following  (found [here](https://github.com/code-not-found/spring-kafka/blob/master/spring-kafka-test-embedded/src/test/java/com/codenotfound/kafka/consumer/SpringKafkaReceiverTest.java))

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext
public class SpringKafkaReceiverTest {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringKafkaReceiverTest.class);

    private static String RECEIVER_TOPIC = "receiver.t";

    @Autowired
    private Receiver receiver;

    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> template;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;

    @ClassRule
    public static KafkaEmbedded embeddedKafka = new KafkaEmbedded(1, true, RECEIVER_TOPIC);

    // Rest of tests body
}
```

I googled a little, but I cannot find which is the aim to use `@DirtiesContext`. Can someone clarify me this point?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When used with a `@ClassRule` embedded kafka, `@DirtiesContext` does not affect the broker; the broker is stopped via `@AfterClass`.

We generally recommend using `@DirtiesContext` at the class level because we don't want the test framework to cache the application context, since it is likely to have active components (`@KafkaListener` etc). We want them to stop since the broker will be killed when the class exits.

If a method is marked `@DirtiesContext` in this case, it has no effect.

If the embedded kafka is defined as a bean instead of a `@ClassRule`, its lifecycle is controlled by the application context instead of JUnit. In this case, method level `@DirtiesContext` will stop the broker as well as a class level annotation.

Answer (score 2):

[From Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#dirtiescontext):

> @DirtiesContext indicates that the underlying Spring ApplicationContext has been dirtied during the execution of a test (i.e., modified or corrupted in some manner — for example, by changing the state of a singleton bean) and should be closed. When an application context is marked dirty, it is removed from the testing framework’s cache and closed. As a consequence, the underlying Spring container will be rebuilt for any subsequent test that requires a context with the same configuration metadata.

I don't have experience with spring-kafka, but I guess they are using it to clean messages generated by the test. But that would be very wasteful for test suite to have a lot of `@DirtiesContext` tests, because Spring context is not cached. In bigger projects it can take minutes to spin up Spring context, thus such annotated test can take so much time.

Therefore I fallback to `@DitriesContext` only if there is no other option. In case of `KafkaEmbedded` I would bet there is the way to throw away all the messages in `@AfterClass` test hook.

Comment: `@DirtiesContext` is recommended at the class level to stop active components when the tests exit. If, however, you use the same context configuration in multiple classes then you might want to move the embedded kafka to the context instead of using it in a class rule. See my answer for more information.